# Increasing column width does not increase the length at which the text is truncated ExtJS 4.2

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4

I have been assigned to fix some bugs on an old project that uses ExtJS version 4.2.

The problem I am experiencing right now is that I have a `Ext.grid.Panel` which has columns defined and one of the columns contains text that might be long and as it should it truncates it but the problem is that when the user increases the width of the column is does not update the truncated text to suit the new available space.

After wondering around the web searching for some I found this [thread](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?248901-Column-Layout-manageOverflow) one of the guys stated that 4.2.1 provides a fix for this but not in 4.2.

Is the any workaround for someone using Version 4.2?

Comment: Well, if you want to stick to an initial release that has been superseded by four or five bugfix releases (if it isn't already, 4.2.5 should be released soon), I guess you have to backport the fix.

Comment: @Alexander I really don't want to stick to that version, it is just that a new version of the app is about to be launched this month and I am just doing maintenance for the time being and upgrading the library would require some serious testing for stability.

Comment: I can suggest for `grid overrides` which can fix this issue in your current version.But YES, you need to find that code overrides.Now, how can you deduce change override code ? copy source code for gird 4.2.0 and grid 4.2.1.Compare both file..Check which method you exactly need to override..Copy that code from 4.2.1 file and add overrides for same..Happy Overriding !!!